# Компиляция nodejs

Tags: node.js

Подскажите что за архив скачивается на главной странице nodejs? Как его ставить, в исходниках должен быть скрипт configure, либо deb пакет должен быть, а с этим zip архивом что делать?

Comment: архив нужно собирать. проще установить менеджером пакетов https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Comment: А Операционная система какая?

Answer (score 0):

Этот архив нужно собирать. Вы можете на сайте NodeJS скачать уже собранную под вашу ОС интересующую вас версию. Или же воспользоваться [менеджером пакетов](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/), как вам подсказали в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

Проверил версии доступные по советам выше. Обновления 5-ти месячные. Пришел к выводу что лучше скачать архив нужной версии и собрать самому. Для Debian, предварительно поставив пакет checkinstall это можно сделать так:

- распаковать архив и переименовать каталог, убрав букву v из версии
- зайти внутрь каталога и выполнить ./configure
- для многоядерных ПК # make -jN && checkinstall -D -y , где N - количество ядер.

Если собирать не из под рута, собранный deb-пакет будет лежать внутри каталога и его нужно будет установить вручную.